# How do I produce mixed case SVG elements like flowRegion in victor

Tags: ruby

I am using gem https://github.com/DannyBen/victor to generate SVG in ruby. My goal is to reproduce simple Inkscape SVG that flows text into an irregular path. The gem author claims that he has implemented all SVG methods, but I can not find the way to produce mixed case elements like flowRegion. Please help.

Comment: I believe flowRegion is part of SVG 1.2, not SVG 1.1 which the gem produces.

Comment: I'm going to export SVG, created with another tool, to eps. Then I will try to embed that eps into pdf with prawn.